# Android : Horizontal slide activity (such as Play Store)

Tags: android, android-activity, slide

What is the best way to make the sliding activity and / or of images such us Play Store ? I know it is ViewPager, but is it good for image sliding? are there any other methods ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should probably read a bit about [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html), [GalleryView](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.co.il/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html) and [Pager](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

good luck.